# Why does Firebase Storage read request never return?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am accessing Firebase storage from Swift in iOS 10.3. Firebase storage version is 2.0.0.

I have uploaded 3 images to Firebase storage. I am unable to access them, however there is no error returned. Instead the completion block is never called. Even if I change the path to something obviously wrong, it still throws no error, just the completion block never gets entered.

The connection to the system should be fine, because moments before that I read the image filenames from the Firebase database.

Here is the relevant code for accessing storage, it is quite straigh forward:

```
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let imageRef = storageRef.child( "product_images/\(imageName)" )

    imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if let data = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            completion( .success(image!) )
        } else {
            completion( .failure(error!) )
        }
    }
```

Does anybody know what is the reason or clues as to where to look for the cause of this?